# Excel VBA - Execution Time Of Macro Slower After Each Execution

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that works as following:

1. Refresh a query that has roughly 10.000 rows.
2. Split the data in various 2D Arrays, depending on some criteria (I have in total a dozen different 2D Arrays).
3. Paste each 2D Array in a different sheet.

When I run the macro the first time it takes ~18 seconds, on the second run ~30 seconds, on the third run ~35 seconds, on the fourth run ~45 seconds and so on. The data from the query is exactly the same at every run (it doesn't change so frequently, or it can change of at most one or two lines).

Can somebody explain me if there are some kind of memory issues I'm not aware of? I also tried to set the matrix equal to Nothing after is pasted on the sheet but this didn't change the slowdown at every run. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. the code is long and I feel it would be useless to paste it all here. It works more or less as follows:

```
Sub GetMatrix()
    Dim Matrix As Variant, IndexMatrix As Long, i As Long, NoRows As Long
    IndexMatrix = 0
    ReDim Matrix(IndexMatrix, 2)
    NoRows = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    For i = 2 To NoRows
        If Cells(i, 1) = "Something" Then
            Matrix(IndexMatrix, 0) = "Something"
            Matrix(IndexMatrix, 1) = "Something"
            Matrix(IndexMatrix, 2) = "Something"
            IndexMatrix = IndexMatrix + 1
            ReDim Preserve Matrix(IndexMatrix, 2)
        End If
    Next
    GetMatrix = Matrix
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know what the issue here is. But in the case of performance problem I would get rid of slow ReDim Preserve first (big array and shrink in the end or collection maybe?). And why don't you read cells to array? Reading from worksheet in each iteration is very slow too. Read the whole range to array  and later check if is equal to "something"

Comment: The first time it runs in ~18 seconds which would be fine for me. So the Redim Preserve or reading the cells from the sheet is not the issue. I have the feeling that I'm somehow filing up memory with the 2D Arrays I'm creating. I'm not sure of this tho.

Comment: So check this in Locals Window, especially second iteration

Comment: Is `GetMatrix` a function which must return a variant? Otherwise, why the last code line (`GetMatrix = Matrix`)?

Comment: Yes, my bad, GetMatrix is a Function, not a Sub

Comment: I will try posting an optimized such function. `Redim Preserve` in case of each iteration it is not good in terms of memory handling...

Comment: Don't you use the two obtained arrays immediately after you obtain them? Do you keep them in a `Public` variable and use them after some such runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next adapted function, please:

```
Function GetMatrix() As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, Matrix As Variant
    Dim IndexMatrix As Long, i As Long, LastRow As Long

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value
    ReDim Matrix(2, UBound(arr)) 'to admit redim preserve (only on the last dimension) at the end
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If arr(i, 1) = "Something" Then
            Matrix(0, IndexMatrix) = "Something"
            Matrix(1, IndexMatrix) = "Something"
            Matrix(2, IndexMatrix) = "Something"
            IndexMatrix = IndexMatrix + 1
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve Matrix(2, IndexMatrix - 1)
    GetMatrix = Matrix
End Function
```

Comment: I'll try it, but why is ReDim Preserve an issue since the first time the macro is Run, it takes just 18 seconds?

Comment: @Lorenzo: When you handle a small amount of data, it is not so dangerous, but anyhow it is bad for memory. `ReDim Preserve` copies the existing array to a new location with a larger memory allocation. So, it can be a whole pile of overhead. `Redim` just creates the new larger memory allocation without copying the data from the existing array so there is very little overhead. That's why a good practice is to firstly `Redim` it in a way to be sure that it will have place for all elements you need to load. And use `Redim Preserve` only at the end, using the iteration loading element...

Comment: Changed the code as suggested, but the issue is still there: slower at every run.